# SPListItem.Workflows always returns zero items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

```
SPList list = web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(listGuid), false);
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(listItemId));
string currentStatus = item["Status"].ToString();
if (currentStatus == "Pending Approval")
{
    SPWorkflowCollection workflows = item.Workflows;
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Why does `item.Workflows` ALWAYS return nothing, even though I know there is a workflow running for this item.

I'm also sure I have the correct `SPListItem` object; the `currentStatus` condition confirms this.

I found these two questions that are related, but refer to SPListItem.Tasks rather than SPListItem.Workflows (perhaps they're related):

[SPListItem.Tasks always empty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50814/splistitem-tasks-always-empty) 
[SPWorkflow.Tasks is empty when not in debug](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69239/spworkflow-tasks-is-empty-when-not-in-debug)

Comment: Please make sure you are referring to the correct list with which the workflow is associated not to the task list of the worklow.

Comment: Avjit, as I mentioned, I'm sure I am referring to the correct list as I have the correct item in `item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why it's returning an empty collection.

In 2013 you can enumerate instances using following code:

Reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase.dll`

```
WorkflowServicesManager workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listGuid, listItemId);
foreach (var instance in workflowInstances)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Amal, thanks for your answer. In the end I went a different route to solve the problem and didn't have to use SPListItem.Workflows. Though I didn't get to try your suggestion, I have a feeling it was a safer route to go, so I'll mark it as the answer.